# NoClassDefFoundError while running Spark depending neo4j jar(scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, jar

I have a program trying to connect to Neo4j database and run on Spark, `testApp.scala`, and I package it using `sbt package` to package it in `a.jar` with dependencies according to [this_contribution](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) (I already have the `neo4j-spark-connector-2.0.0-M2.jar`)

```
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
libraryDependencies += "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.0.0-M2"
```

However while I tried `spark-submit --class "testApp" a.jar` it turns out to be 
a **NoClassDefFoundError**

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/spark/Neo4j$` in the code `val n = Neo4j(sc)`

There are 2 more things I have to mention

1) I used `jar vtf` to check the content in `a.jar`, it only has `testApp.class`, no class of `neo4j` is in it, but the package process was success (does it mean the `neo4j-spark-connector-2.0.0-M2.jar` is not packaged in?)

2) I can use `spark-shell --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.0.0-M2` and type the code in `testApp.scala`, there is no problem (e.g. the wrong line above is `val n = Neo4j(sc)` but it can work in spark-shell)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `--jars` option with `spark-submit`. For example

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "fully-qualified-class-name" --master "master-url" --jars "path-of-your-dependency-jar"
```

or you can also use `spark.driver.extraClassPath="jars-class-path"` to solve the issue.Hope this helps.

Comment: I have found the solution and put it below, thank you very much anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As the content in the `.jar` does not contain `Neo4j` class, it is the packaging problem.

What we should modify is `sbt`, instead of `sbt package`, we should use `sbt clean assembly` instead. This helps create a `.jar` pack containing all the dependencies in it.

If you use only `sbt package`, the compile progress is ok, but it will not pack `neo4j-*.jar` into your `.jar`. So during the run time it throws an `NoClassDefError`